# Scheduled annotated method on a prototyped bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a bean with scope "prototype" (not singleton) with a @Scheduled annotated method.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TestManager {

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
  public void updateStatuses(){
      log.info("Scheduled update");
  }

}
```

I call an instance of the bean when I need it and I expect each instance to launch the scheduled timer.
 The scheduler annotation doesn't seem to work unless I remove the scope and I make the bean a singleton again.

Is there a good workaround? Why isn't this possible?

Comment: How do you are getting the TestManager bean instance ?

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12872 . Basically anything else as singleton beans aren't supported before Spring 4.3.

Comment: Many thanks @M.Deinum!